# Haskell - map values of a list of tuples with another function

Tags: haskell

I am writing some code that creates a histogram based on the values in a list of tuples.

The list looks like this:

```
[("her",4),("she",2),("friend",1)]
```

This is my code so far:

```
-- creates a histogram string of each tuple
makeHistogramRow :: (String, Int) -> String
makeHistogramRow (str, int) = replicate int '*' ++ " -> " ++ str ++ "\n"

-- creates a histogram for each tuple in the list
makeHistogram :: [(String, Int)] -> String
makeHistogram (str, int) = concat (map makeHistogramRow (str, int))

main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ makeHistogram [("her",4),("she",2),("friend",1)]
```

I am trying to map each value in the tuple to the

```
makeHistogramRow
```

function but it doesnt seem to be working, i know im missing an anonymous function or something but i cant seem to figure it out...

The output should look like this:

```
**** -> her
** -> she
* -> friend
```

Does anyone know what im missing? Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the intention is here, but you can't use `(str, int)` to pattern match against a list. I think you mean just `makeHistogram xs  = concat (map makeHistogramRow xs)`. (You can quite easily write this definition "point free" - that is, without referring to the argument at all - which for simple functions like this is considered good style.)

Comment: oh wow, thats interesting, thank you that worked! :)

Comment: You're getting some type errors. Have you read them carefully? What specifically are you struggling with or confused by there?

Comment: `makeHistogram = concatMap makeHistogramRow`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments,

```
makeHistogram :: [(String, Int)] -> String
makeHistogram (str, int) = concat (map makeHistogramRow (str, int))
```

will not type check because `(str,int)` is a pattern of type `(a,b)` rather than `[(a,b)]`.That is, it is a tuple, not a list of tuples. To make your code work you could say

```
makeHistogram :: [(String, Int)] -> String
makeHistogram ls = concat (map makeHistogramRow ls)
```

or, better

```
makeHistogram :: [(String, Int)] -> String
makeHistogram ls = concatMap makeHistogramRow ls
```

or even better

```
makeHistogram :: [(String, Int)] -> String
makeHistogram = concatMap makeHistogramRow
```